# Linux thread implementation

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, linux-kernel, pthreads

I was reading about thread implementation in linux. It seems that linux infact models threads as "special" processes (using **clone** system call) passing appropriate flags to it so that address space is shared.

Multiple threads that spawned this way would have separate **pid** (process id - logical thread id) but same **tgid** (thread group id - logical process id). How would thread spawning be quicker than process spawning (since threads are modelled as process)?

How would operations like **TLB** flushes work? Would context switch between (logical) threads still be be cheap?

Comment: "How would thread spawning be quicker than process spawning?" - It is because kernel doesn't need to create separate address space for the spawned thread. "Would context switch between (logical) threads still be be cheap?" - Again, because threads share address space, there is no need change address space when switch between the threads.

Comment: Hmmm. Then, MMU for example would use thread group id (not process id) while generating physical address from virtual address? But AFAIK, concept of thread group id was added later on in the kernel.